# Is it possible to associate a certificate using two private/public keys?

Tags: iphone, xcode, certificate, provisioning

I've got a weird situation here; I developed an app in 2011 using a macbook (private key: alida).. then a couple of months ago was having some problems migrating cert to another machine so just decided to revoke it and generate another certificate now using another set of private keys (francisco)

The situation is that now I have both certificates using two private keys in the keychain (and the old cert expired);

The question: is there a way to pair both priv keys (francisco & alida) with one certificate in the keychain? or I just have to left one of my apps behind? both apps I already in the Appstore;

Look hows my keychain (new machine) looks like:

[image]

Any suggestion on what should I do? is there any hope to fix this?

Thanks in advanced.

[edit]

another screenshots from the "my certificates" tab in keychain; so, basically I lost one my apps (no updates ever?) I think If thats the case, I will revoke current cert again and renew it with the keys from 2011 (first app generated) and forget the other one :/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, keys come in pairs: (public, private). A certificate is just a file containing your public key plus some extra data including a "subject" which is information associating the public key to a specific person or entity (such as a DNS address) and, most importantly, a signature from a signing authority certifying (hence "certificate") that the public key is owned by the entity. These key-pairs are inextricably bound: there is no meaningful way to associate the private key from one key-pair to the public key/certificate of a different key-pair.

Normally, a signer (such as Apple in this case) will not generate two certificates with the exact same subject without revoking the earlier certificate first.

If you have an app at the iTunes store signed with a revoked certificate, it needs to be replaced with one signed by the newer, non-revoked certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to pair both priv keys. You should now go with new priv key.